# Meteor highlights all text on click

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have an issue with the website/web app I am developing (http://stokvella.herokuapp.com/) : whenever I click on the web page, all the text is highlighted.

Why is this happening, and how can I solve this issue?

I am using Meteor along with Blaze. If you need any more information, I will gladly provide it, however I am unsure as to what else might help solve this problem.

Thank you for your help :)

Greg

Comment: need more info , i can't understand what you mean with "highlighted" also post your code ...

Comment: I'am thinking that you have some java script that does it. find the script and remove it. Add your code for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add javascript

```
$(document).click(function(){
  //add code
});
```